# Fiber Cable speed tester

Tags: layer1, fiber, cable, cabling

How to select Fiber Cable (multi-mode or single mode). For example, if i need fiber backbone around 700 meters with 2 GB speed, how i choose, om 2, om 3 or OS 1 & Os 2. Is there any calculator or calculations available for it..?

Binoj

Comment: Really, you just need to know the characteristics of the fiber types. Many fiber vendors have those listed on the web sites.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

So you don't specify the connection type (fibre channel?  Ethernet? SONET?) but it's safe to say that at 700M you're outside the realm of what should be run with multimode on just about anything.

Since the link needs to be single mode you'd likely have an easier time just using OS1, which has somewhat higher attenuation but is less fragile and thus much easier to run within a building.  The lesser attenuation of OS2 isn't going to be a factor until you're into many tens of kilometers.